# docker and jwilder/nginx-proxy http/https issue

Tags: docker, https, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm using docker on osx via `boot2docker`.

I have 2 hosts: `site1.loc.test.com` and `site2.loc.test.com` pointed to ip address of docker host.

Both should be available via `80` and `443` ports.

So I'm using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` for reverse proxy purposes.

But in fact when I'm running all of them via `docker-compose` every time I try to open via `80` port I get redirect to `443` `(301 Moved Permanently)`.

May be I've missed something in `jwilder/nginx-proxy` configuration?

#### docker-compose.yml

```
proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"

site1:
  image: httpd:2.4
  volumes:
    - site1:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: site1.loc.test.com
  expose:
    - "80"

site2:
  image: httpd:2.4
  volumes:
    - site2:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: site2.loc.test.com
  expose:
    - "80"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your configuration should be correct, but it seems that this is the intended behaviour of `jwilder/nginx-proxy`. See these lines in the file `nginx.tmpl`: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl#L89-L94

It seems that if a certificate is found, you will always be redirected to https.

---

EDIT: I found the confirmation [in the documentation](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#user-content-how-ssl-support-works)

> The behavior for the proxy when port 80 and 443 are exposed is as
>   follows:
>
> - If a container has a usable cert, port 80 will redirect to 443 for that container so that HTTPS is always preferred when available.

You can still use a [custom configuration](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#per-virtual_host). You could also try to override the file `nginx.tmpl` in a new Dockefile .

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that.

Answer (score 7):

Just to keep this topic up to date, the jwilder/nginx-proxy meanwhile introduced a flag for that: `HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect`; To be set as environment variable.

Further reading [on github](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#how-ssl-support-works)

Answer (score 2):

To serve traffic in both SSL and non-SSL modes without redirecting to SSL, you can include the environment variable HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect (the default is HTTPS_METHOD=redirect).

HTTPS_METHOD must be specified on each container for which you want to override the default behavior.

Here is an example Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./config/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    environment:
      DEFAULT_HOST: my.example.com

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect
      VIRTUAL_HOST: my.example.com
```

Note: As in this example, environment variable `HTTPS_METHOD` must be set on the `app` container, not the `nginx-proxy` container.

Ref: `How SSL Support Works` section for the [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) Docker image.